# Use user defined type (with typedef) as method parameter

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I've defined a new type with this code

```
typedef enum result 
{

     error,
     error1,
     erorr2,

}result;
```

After that I want to implement a method that takes a "result" as parameter

```
- (void) setError:(result)errorNumber
```

It seems that it is not allowed and give me an compiler error.

Is not possible to use user defined type as method parameters?!?

Comment: Pleeeease can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: I ve moved the tyoedef in prefix file and all work correctly

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the header file that contains the typedef before you use it. For example:

File1.h:

```
typedef enum { a, b, c } resultType;
```

File2.h:

```
#import "File1.h"

...


- (void) someMethod:(resultType)param;
```

`File1.h` can be imported into as many header (or implementation) files as you need.

Comment: sorry write mistake

- (void) setTError:(result)errorNumber;

but also in this case it return me an error

Comment: @Luca Where is your typedef? Is it in the same file? What is the compiler error message?

Comment: The complier errore compare only if i try to use my user defined type ad parameter of a method in another .h files. I' ve imported the .h file with the type declaration...is not possible to use that in another file thah import the header with the typedef? thanks

Comment: @Luca I've changed my answer (and your question) to reflect the new information you added.

Comment: @Luca Also, in general you should include the actual error message rather than just say that there was one.